# Why was Anakin Skywalker taken to the Grand Medical Facility on planet Coruscant?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Mustafar is a mining colony on the Outer Rim and Coruscant is the heart of the galaxy. Could the emperor not find a DD-13 medical assistant and 2-1B surgical droids anywhere else closer to Mustafar? Could Kamino clone tech be on Coruscant?

Comment: If the logic is "the emperor wanted his new apprentice to receive the best quality of meducal attention" How would that not include cloning?

Answer (score 1):

The very prominent reason might be because the Emperor knew that Anakin would last the time back to Coruscant (they literally jumped to lightspeed), also because Coruscant was the capital of the galaxy and the Emperor wanted his new apprentice to receive the best quality of medical attention. Since the galaxy was now under the control of the Sith overlords, he wanted to ensure that every planet in the galaxy knew about their power and influence. There were no Jedi warriors left to fight or resist them.

Comment: Well that's not 100% accurate. In the second current Marvel Darth Vader comic series titled, 'Darth Lord of the Sith', Vader is immediately tasked to hunt down and kill many of the remaining Jedi after he awakes from surgery and confronts Sidious. (Not to mention steal a Jedi he kills lightsaber and bleed it's crystal red to make it his own). But there are Jedi (like Fallen Order's Cal Kestis) that survive Order 66. You're point is still valid, just that not all of the Jedi were gone, despite the Order fell.

Comment: @DarthLocke True, I really forgot about the part of Obi-Wan and Master Yoda surviving. Though I didn't really get the mention of Cal Kestis as I have not read the comics or any books related to _Star Wars_. Thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: It's cool. There's just a lot of new canon! :D